# jQuery.post() - Trouble sending post data

Tags: php, jquery

I have a html file with the following javascript code to call the jquery.post function and post some data to test.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(data) {
         alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
       });
</script>
```

test.php is as follows

```
<?php
   echo "Name: ".$POST['name'];
?>
```

Unfortunately, my alert only shows "name: " without sending back the post data.

Using firebug, however, I can see that the post data is in fact being sent. So I'm very confused as to why $POST isn't working in my php file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The javascript function is fine. The problem is at the server side. You should write `$_POST`, not `$POST`.

```
echo "Name: ".$POST['name'];
```

Comment: Sorry guys, but didnt I say that in my answer first?

Answer (score 2):

Your data is being stored in an array like structure...

As such, you should alert the data as follows:

```
alert("Data Loaded: Name=" + data('name') + " Time="+ data('time'));
```

Also, there is a typo in your php

```
echo "Name: ".$_POST['name'];
```

You need the _. e.g. not $POST, but $_POST

Answer (score 1):

its `$_POST['variable']` not `$POST` check your php syntax http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php